# Difference between compile time and run time

Tags: sml, read-eval-print-loop

What is the difference between compile time and run time in SML?

After writing some SML code, we hit enter. But I don't understand, are we actually compiling 
it or running it? For example

```
- fun len [] = 0 | len (x::xs) = 1 + len xs;      /* hit enter*/
val len = fn : 'a list -> int
```

after hitting enter, we get `val len = fn : 'a list -> int` as a result. Is this a runtime result or a complile time result?

I really don't understand what is happening behind the scene.

Answer (score 5):

In your example you seem to use an interpreter, then the difference between *compile time* and *run time* might not be so obvious. In principle it is:

- *Compile Time*: The phase where source-code is compiled into more low-level instructions (e.g., machine code). During this phase also things like type inference and syntax checks are done. All errors that are guaranteed to be caught during this phase (like *type errors* for Standard ML) can never occur during *run time*, which is a very nice thing, since you know that after successful compilation certain kinds of error can never occur. (*Compile time* is also when *compiler optimizations* would be applied.)
- *Run Time*: This is when your program is actually executed (be it as machine code or some other representation): Inputs are given to the program and results are computed.

For your explicit example: During *compile time* it is only checked that your input is syntactically correct and the type of `len` is inferred. During *run time* the program that is represented by your input is executed, but since there are no computations in that program (it just defines the new function `len` without calling it), nothing has to be done.

Answer (score 1):

First of all remember that before your code can be run, it must be compiled. So there two processes which should occur that is - Compiling and Running - . Therefore Compile time, is the time it takes to Compile code ,and Run time  is the actual time it takes to run.

Hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

Most implementations of ML feature an "incremental compiler" as part of the read-eval-print loop.  So when you enter a new top-level declaration, it is first compiled (including static type-checking and code-generation) and then the resulting native code is run.

A system that can compile at run-time like that might look odd to people who are used to batch-mode compilation in the manner of C or C++.  Even Java is more static in that respect than necessary, but the Scala read-eval-print loop demonstrates that it can be done not just in ML.  Note that this might look like an interpreter, but is really a compiler producing code at run-time.

The general idea is rather old, coming from ancient LISP times, but LISP did not have a compiler initially and was often just interpreted without compilation.